# OpenVZ: Node iptables doesn't append rules

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, linux-networking, openvz

I want to make a set of rules on iptables inside of a node, but it seems that the iptables isn't appending all the rules or somehow and kick me out everytime I run the following script (I'm using this set of rules in other servers and works fine):

```
# Allow connections that are already connected to your server
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow connections to SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allowing connections to HTTP/HTTPS
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow icmp input but limit it to 10/sec
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 10/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow all incoming traffic from local
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Changing the default policy for INPUT chain
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

The problem that I found (I guess) is that the last line (DROP anything) is interpreted as one and that's why the server kicks me out.

I already change the conf for vz:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ipt_REJECT ipt_tos ipt_limit ipt_multiport iptable_filter iptable_mangle ipt_TCPMSS ipt_tcpmss ipt_ttl ipt_length ipt_state xt_state ip_conntrack"
```

Any help with this is aprecciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen more problems with OpenVZ and using "ESTABLISHED,RELATED". Regretfully, I haven't been able to find out how to fix the OpenVZ installations that for some reason don't allow stateful iptables in containers.

But with the reasonably simple IPTable rules you have, do you really need them to be stateful? I think the following will work just as good:

```
# Allow connections to SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allowing connections to HTTP/HTTPS
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow icmp input but limit it to 10/sec
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 10/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow all incoming traffic from local
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Changing the default policy for INPUT chain
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```